# Count Occurrence of Cell Array to Cell Array Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've got 2 string cell arrays, one is the unique version of the other. I would like to count the number of occurrence of each values in the unique cell array given the other cell array. I got a large cell array so I thought I'd try my best to find answers to a more faster approach as oppose to looping...

An example:

```
x = {'the'
 'the'
 'aaa'
 'b'
 'the'
 'c'
 'c'
 'd'
 'aaa'}

y=unique(x)
```

I am looking for an output in any form that contains something like the following:

```
'aaa' = 2
'b'   = 1
'c'   = 2
'd'   = 1
'the' = 3
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to count the indices `unique` finds:

```
[y, ~, idx] = unique(x);
counts = histc(idx, 1:length(y));
```

which gives

```
counts =

   2
   1
   2
   1
   3
```

in the same order as `y`.

`histc` is my default fallback for counting things, but [the function I always forget about](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is probably better in this case:

```
counts = accumarray(idx, 1);
```

should give the same result and is probably more efficient.